# Date format when filtering GridView in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

MySql table stores the date in this format: `2016-08-01`. 
My GridView table shows this date in this format `01.08.2016`. 
The DatePicker widget filters the selected date in this format `01.08.2016`
BUT FILTERING DOES NOT HAPPEN. I think that is because MySQL format is `2016-08-01` and I am filtering in `01.08.2016` format. How do I fix this, so that `01.08.2016` format is filtered right?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data format at the time of fillterting by using this

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format